# project's template using app's static files

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this sounds as a silly and long question but I'm new to django and I've searched about this and I still couldn't fix my problem.
If I'm extending an html, say home.html

```
{% extends "blog/home.html" %}
```

in an html of another app, say article/id.html; and blog/home.html has its own static files that it uses, style.css would be loaded when opening id.html wouldn't?

my problem is, under myproject folder, the one that contains urls.py etc, I've created a dir called templates

```
|--myproject
|   |--blog
|   |    |-- templates
|   |    |    |-- blog
|   |    |    |    |-- home.html
|   |    |-- static
|   |    |    |-- css
|   |    |        |-- styles.html
|   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |-- models.py
|   |    |-- tests.py
|   |    |-- urls.py
|   |    |-- views.py
|   |--article
|   |    |-- templates
|   |    |    |-- article
|   |    |    |    |-- id.html
|   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |-- models.py
|   |    |-- tests.py
|   |    |-- urls.py
|   |    |-- views.py
|   |--myproject
|   |    |-- templates
|   |    |    |-- myproject
|   |    |    |    |-- login.html
|   |    |    |    |-- logout.html
|   |    |    |    |-- loggedin.html
|   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |-- models.py
|   |    |-- tests.py
|   |    |-- urls.py
|   |    |-- views.py
```

I have modified the urls and view of myproject, urls.py:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^article/', include('article.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
```

these login.html, logout.html, loggedin.html and id.html all extend home.html.
For some reason, when I run my server and try to go to

```
localhost:8000/accounts/login
```

, it tries to get styles.css from

```
[27/Aug/2013 23:34:06] "GET /accounts/login/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2875
```

not from

```
static/css/styles.css
```

as I expected, but it works fine when i try to open the id.html from article app.

this is how I'm importing the css in blog/home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css"/>
```

Am I doing something wrong? how can I can get the myproject html's to use the static files from the blog app? Note I'm using Django 1.5

Comment: Please show how you include css in to your blog/home.html template. Most probably you are doing something wrong in there...

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like changing the way I retrieve static files in htmls fixed the problem.
I was doing this before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css"/>
```

and changing it to this fixed it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `STATIC_URL` in settings must end with a slash `/`. Locally, when developing it should look like this: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Do You have that?